# Sending content of cron with cron via email

Tags: email, cron, backup

is there a simple way to send the content of the cron as an email by cron? Like: I would to receive a "backup" of my crontabs every month via email.

Thnx for your kind help,
Dirk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for that problem
0 0 1 * * crontab -l | mail -s "Backup Cron" youemail@mail.com
and try on https://crontab.guru/every-month if you make cron schedule

Answer (score 0):

Ah thnx. Works great.
In case anyone else is looking, I also found another option:
mail -s "Cron-Backup" name@domain.de